# Asus VivoPC VM60 Poor Wifi Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, wireless

So I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Asus VM60 machine and the WiFi works, however it is really slow and is constantly losing signal, my windows laptop and phone are fine on my network but for some reason Ubuntu is not playing nice with it. I have updated to the latest kernel as well as making sure the OS is up to date.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of "channels" on wi-fi. Very likely you're using the same channel along with all of your neighbors, and somehow your system is the weakest of the bunch. If you have an Android phone, install the "Wifi Channel Analyzer" and you'll see which channels are not getting any use. There may be other problems, but this is an easy place to start. If Channels are crammed, then you'll do much better fixing that first. BTW, you reassign/allocate the channels on your wi-fi router. (I think)!  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find latest driver.
and go to interface -> property -> Advanced -> Wifi config -> Do not use "performance", choose "Wifi", and it may be better.